# "See" vs "Can see" - ultimate question

Tags: verbs, american-english, british-english

When I went to school, I was taught that "to see" = "to understand", but if you want to speak about eye-vision, you should say "can see". For example: *I can see a cat on this tree*. This would be wrong: *I see a cat on this tree*.

Is it really wrong? I have a hunch it might be a British-American difference, could someone confirm it? At school we always learn the British version of English. Do British say "I see a cat"? Do Americans say it? Which one is used more often?

I read: ["I see" or "I can see"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210520/i-see-or-i-can-see) and ["I can see someone " vs "I see someone"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215396/i-can-see-someone-vs-i-see-someone) - but here the answers consider an obvious case where you put stress or not on the ability of seeing.
["Can you see it?" vs "Do you see it?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148900/can-you-see-it-vs-do-you-see-it) - here they write about how similar are these two forms and that both seem correct. I'd be interested about regional differences, if they exist.

Comment: I can see you've been seriously misled! Auxiliary ***can*** has no real relevance to how metaphorically the verb ***to see*** might be used (***can*** be used! :)

Answer (score 3):

As a native (British) speaker, I would use both interchangeably. For **see** you could use it to refer to having sight of something:

> I **see** a ship on the water.

You might then choose to use **can see** non-literally:

> I **can see** that this might cause trouble.

If there is any difference to be sensed in everyday speech, I might suggest that **see** sounds a little more formal, though not by much. Otherwise, I can't immediately think of examples that wouldn't work interchangeably.

Comment: If there's a slight difference, it's that you would say "I see a cat in the tree" if you have just noticed the cat, and "I can see a cat" to mean that it is near enough to see, or that it is within your field of view.

Comment: @KateBunting Perhaps, but then say you're peering through branches to find a cat, it's entirely possible upon sighting said cat you'd come out with "I see a cat!" There are, of course, certain setups that might elicit "I can..." at the start of a sentence, but that feels a different discussion to this one.